# WSUS multi server automation - how to determine Windows version for each KB names?

Tags: windows, windows-update, poshwsus

As WSUS built in downstream replica is not possible in our environment - isolated sites with file transfer through dedicated secure file transfer system - I would like to automate the distribution of updates from my Master WSUS to branch servers using scripts, but not in all branches we have all windows versions and I would like only distribute relevant updates to each branch server. The problem is we will then have to manually maintain a file or table which determines which KB is for which version so this can't be fully automated.
It would be perfect to find some online DB or even web-page I could easily query to get this up to date information or solve this in another way.
I found no solutions searching online. Do you have any ideas?